# snd_rawmidi_open() waits forever - no error message

Tags: linux, alsa, c, midi

I am trying to use ALSA for MIDI purposes in C.

My problem is, snd_rawmidi_open() sort of "crashes" (waits forever like a while loop) when using valuable arguments :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    snd_rawmidi_t *handle_in = 0;
    int err;
    fprintf(stderr, "TEST 1\n");
    err = snd_rawmidi_open(&handle_in,NULL,"hw:1,0,0",0);
    fprintf(stderr,"TEST 2\n");
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr,"snd_rawmidi_open failed: %d\n",err);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "TEST 3\n");
    exit(0);    
}
```

"hw:1,0,0" is a MIDI keyboard. When I use an invalid value like "foo", it gives an error. With a valid one, the program displays "TEST 1" and pauses.

Any idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `snd_rawmidi_open` waits until the requested port is available.

If you do not want this, add the `SND_RAWMIDI_NONBLOCK` flag (and reset it afterwards with `snd_rawmidi_nonblock()` if you want the read/write calls to be blocking).

Comment: You're right, in my case Jack was already using this port : one can check the input port using `amidi -d -p{port}` - this said me "hw:1,0,0 : device or resource busy".